PHP interprets \n new line in array, but not when I pass the same string in a $_POST variable to the array
So, I am trying to understand what is the difference with my string now that it has arrived through a FORM POST instead of a string which i declare in the variable inside my code, when I echo the POST variable it is the correct string. When it reaches Telegram, the new line is no longer interpreted as a new line.
This is part of my code and it works as expected:
$dynamicMessage = "Line One \nLineTwo";

// Parameters to be sent in the request
$params = array(
    'chat_id' => $chatId,
    'text' => $dynamicMessage,
    'parse_mode' => 'HTML'
);

Output in my Telegram chat from my Telegram Bot:
Line One 
LineTwo


Now, I switch to POST to this and assign to the variable, it does not work as expected:
$dynamicMessage = trim($_POST["updatemessage"]);

// Parameters to be sent in the request
$params = array(
    'chat_id' => $chatId,
    'text' => $dynamicMessage,
    'parse_mode' => 'HTML'
);

Output in my Telegram chat from my Telegram Bot:
Line One \nLineTwo


Escape sequences are only processed in string literals in the program source, not in data.

What does $dynamicMessage really contain? A string containing a line break, or a string with the two characters \n in the middle? Also, are you sure your problem is related to cURL or HTML?

$dynamicMessage = "Line One \nLineTwo";
That is what is inside the variable.
I sent the same string via HTML FORM POST in a text input and also tried textarea input. I can echo the POST variable and see the correct string. Just the output in Telegram - does not interpres the /n as a new line, but instead shows it as part of the characters.

@Barmar - any idea how I can workaround?

@NicoHaase - when I first posted the question, the correct output I wanted to show you was not on a new line so I added a BR here, now the BR was showing so I edited the q again.. sorry for the muddle. I can assure you the variable and the posted variable bot have the same string which has a \n as part of it.

In PHP, when you hardcode a string with newline characters like "\n", they are interpreted directly as newlines. However, when you get a string from a POST operation, the "\n" in the string is treated as a literal backslash followed by an "n", rather than as a newline character.
The fix:
$dynamicMessage = str_replace("\\n", "\n", trim($_POST["updatemessage"]));

Why are you getting data with literal \n in it in the first place? Why doesn't the client send actual newlines if that's what is desired?

@Barmar - client sending actual new lines does not work in the output which is a telegram chat.

In PHP, when you hardcode a string with newline characters like "\n", they are interpreted directly as newlines. However, when you get a string from a POST operation, the "\n" in the string is treated as a literal backslash followed by an "n", rather than as a newline character.
The fix:
$dynamicMessage = str_replace("\\n", "\n", trim($_POST["updatemessage"]));


Note that this won't work correctly if there data contains an escaped \n that shouldn't be replaced.

To clarify this answer, when you set a variable using double-quotes PHP will read the source code and turn escape sequences (\x) into their non-character counterparts. For example, \n becomes <newline>. Your code is then reading data from a POST form. The POST form did not send you a newline - it sent you a \  character and an n character, so that's what you get.
